# Laravel & Ajax return array response no parsing

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

Currently I'm trying to pull some data via ajax and I'm not getting the data to appear properly.

In my ajax call I have this:

```
$.ajax({
      url:"{{ route('pricing.fetch') }}",
      method:"POST",
      data:{select:select, value:value, _token:_token, dependent:dependent, productId:productId},
      success:function(result)
      {

      $("ul[data-dependent='quantity']").html(result);
```

This works as expected.  The problem is I'm trying to return data from different tables in my db.  So I'm trying to do it by changing my result in ajax to this.

```
$("ul[data-dependent='quantity']").html(result.productQuantities);
```

The reason for me wanting to do this is because I have multiple drop downs I need.  So I would also like to do another one like this:

```
$("ul[data-dependent='quantity']").html(result.productPaperStock);
```

my controller code is like this:

```
   $data = Product::with(['productQuantity', 'productPaperstock'])->where('ID', $productId)->first();
   // pull the quantity for this product
   $productQuanties = $data->productQuantity;
   $productPaperStock = 'hello';

   $output = '';

   foreach($productQuanties as $productQuantity)
   {
    $output .= "<li><span>" . $productQuantity->quantity_name . "</span></li>";
   }
    return response()->json["productQuanties" => $productQuanties, "productPaperStock" => $productPaperStock]);
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but using this example above I get a 500 error.

Comment: When you use `method: 'post'` the system will expect you to send some data... ajax on jquery uses `method: 'get'` by default, implicit. Could you try and see what happens? Or better, replace `method: 'post'` by `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: @Rafael yes I'm posting some data, I just didn't include in the code as it wasn't relevant to getting data form controller.  I'll add it now thou.

Comment: I think I didn't make myself clear, sorry. By **POST** the system will expect data to be saved. If that's not what you want, stick to **GET**, where you are still allowed to send data as parameters.

Comment: @Rafael changed to dataType: 'json and changed route in routes to get instead of post.  Still getting 500 error

Comment: @Rafael Also the reason why I'm using post is because I'm sending some parameters to the server to check for specific data i need returned.

Comment: @FabricioG what does laravel.log tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `dataType: json` option in your ajax request, and then in your controller, you can return `json` response.

Also, you are missing the starting brace in your controller code. The correct code is

```
return response()->json(["productQuanties" => $productQuanties, "productPaperStock" => $productPaperStock])
```

(Note that ...storage/logs/laravel.log is an awesome place to get insights into what's screwing your app:))